# Using WWW in public method of a GameObject in Unity C#

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am beginner in Unity3d and C# and after hours of searching solutions (and building a XML reader in C# based on documentation) I stuck on this problem:

I have two prefab planes tagged as "test" and I want to show images from URL on them as texture when the images loaded.

The planes has an empty Start and Update method and this public one in the **loadImageFromURL.cs**:

```
public IEnumerator changeTexture(string url){
    Debug.Log (url);

    WWW www = new WWW (url);
    yield return www;
    renderer.material.mainTexture = www.texture;
}
```

Then I have an empty gamobject that collects image URLs in the Start() method then I do this:

```
IEnumerator Start () {

    WWW www = new WWW("http://example.com/xmlfile.rss");
    yield return www;
    stream =  new StringReader(www.text);

    /*Here I do all the XML stuff, it provides the URLs from the rss feed there is no error in it*/

    picture =  GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("test");
    loadImageFromURL sc = (loadImageFromURL)picture[0].GetComponent(typeof(loadImageFromURL));

    //here I call the function
    sc.changeTexture(URLs[2]);
}
```

When I simply pass the URL and just return null; in the changeTexture method it show the url when I Debug.Log it. When WWW lines are there it is like nothing happens. Also this exact same WWW code works perfectly as [seen in Unity reference too](http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/ScriptReference/WWW.html)

So I am pretty sure there is something I do not understand about WWW.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't enumerate your result, your code will not be executed. Enumerate your result with a `foreach` or materialize it with a `.ToList()` call or write the functions in a way that does not use [deferred execution](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb669162.aspx).

**Edit:**

Your functions even have parts that will *never* execute. Have a look at the link I provided. Returning an IEnumerable does not make sense in your functions at all. Use normal `return` mechanisms, not `yield return`.